# Y-axis in Netlogo plot

Tags: plot, axis, netlogo

[image]Hello,

I want to create a plot depicting two negative values. One is a very large -ve number and the other is comparatively small. I have attached the resulting chart.I know the magnitude of the green bar is significantly smaller than the other but Is there a way to work around it. Appreciate the help. Thanks in advance.

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Approach 1: make 2 separate graphs.

Approach 2: scale your data to be a percentage deviation from the mean.

Unfortunately, having two different y-scales is not supported.